# Is this invalid JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, url

I wrote this code:

```
(function($) {
 var url = 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-   android/?json=get_all_posts&callback=?';

 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     async: false,
     jsonpCallback: 'callback',
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(json) {
         console.log(json.status);
     console.log(json);
     try{
       json = $.parseJSON(json);
       alert(json);
     }catch(e){
       alert('invalid');
     }
     },
     error: function(e) {
         console.log(e.message);
     }
 });

 })(jQuery);
```

http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts&callback=?
That is JSON url

I get 'Invalid'... If I remove try and catch i get this error: http://prntscr.com/2sf8bd

Comment: Isn't your JSON already parsed when you get it in parameter as you said content-type was 'application/json' ?

Comment: var url = "http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts&callback=?";

Comment: I removed dataType and I got this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You have mentioned `dataType:'jsonp';` so there is no need of `$.parseJSON`

Comment: Also, the URL in your snippet isn't the same as the one you mention in your question...
Just made a fiddle, seems quite OK to me : http://jsfiddle.net/yx8Fm/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Removed `$.parseJSON`, because of `dataType: 'jsonp',` already defined

```
(function($) {
 var url = 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts&callback=?';

 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     async: false,
     jsonpCallback: 'callback',
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(json) {
         console.log(json.status);
         console.log(json);

     },
     error: function(e) {
         console.log(e.message);
     }
 });

 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Paulloz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321425/paulloz) indicated your `json` is already a JSON object: JSfiddle without parse and alert: http://jsfiddle.net/Skadi2k3/cKUD7/